# "Move" app bundle identifier to a new React Native project

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm upgrading an old React Native app, from 0.59.1 to 0.68.0 (which is the last one). Useless to say that it's a huge pain to upgrade all of those dependencies and I'm thinking to create a new project (and move all JS files) instead of upgrading the current one.
But I have a problem: the app is currently in production and I want to make a new project which would result in an update for the old app. I think that the goal to do this is "move" the bundle ID from the previous project, but I really don't know how to do it.
Any ideas? I need tips for both iOS and Android.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Already upgrading to 0.68? The stable version got out a few days ago and a lot of libraries (basically every library) are currently not stating in their docs where to add their dependencies etc. in 0.68 since a lot of stuff moved is added or removed... 0.68 is completely different from 0.67. I would consider to wait a bit with upgrading to 0.68 and upgrade to 0.67 for now. Also since 0.59 is a rather old version, I would take your first suggestion, create a completely new project running on 0.67, installing every package you have in your old project, regularly checking if the build succeeds and then just like you said copy your /src folder to the new project. And yes you need to change your package name to your old one. [Heres](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEjBhwDJp-A) a video on how to do it.